# Show only tweets in TweetDeck (exclude replies)

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

When I add some user as column to the TweetDeck I see both tweets and replies ("Replying to ..."). How to add a user and see only his tweets without/exclude replies?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make a column from the `Search` button rather than from `User`.

Then, customize the search as follows: `from:[user handle without @] -filter:replies`

So, if I wanted every tweet by the @StackOverflow account without their replies, I'd set the following as the search term in my TweetDeck column:
`from:stackoverflow -filter:replies`